# How do I narrow a group of Postgres rows by which has values closest to specific values?

Tags: postgresql, aggregates

I have some data which looks something like this after I run some filters on it:

```
Business Type | Business City | Min Rating | Max Rating
--------------+---------------+------------+-----------
Restaurant    | Barcelona     |          2 |          8
Restaurant    | Barcelona     |          1 |         10
Restaurant    | Madrid        |          4 |          8
Diner         | Madrid        |          5 |          8
Diner         | Madrid        |          1 |          8
Diner         | Barcelona     |          3 |          8
```

I need to return only one row for each business type and city combination. The row I return needs to be the one where the min and max ratings are the closest to specific numbers. For example, I want to return the one closest to a minimum rating of 3 and a max rating of 7. This would result in:

```
Business Type | Business City | Min Rating | Max Rating
--------------+---------------+------------+-----------
Restaurant    | Barcelona     |          2 |          8
Restaurant    | Madrid        |          4 |          8
Diner         | Madrid        |          5 |          8
Diner         | Barcelona     |          3 |          8
```

This is in a Rails 5 application using ActiveRecord. I'm open to using Arel, ActiveRecord DSL, or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Order them by the specific value difference and apply limit.

Comment: Looks like all you need is a `GROUP BY` on the columns that should be unique, and a `min` or `max` for the aggregated columns. What confuses me is that you aggregate the "Min Rating" by taking the maximum...

Comment: @Marek I need one for each grouped pair. You suggestion would limit the rows overall.

Comment: @Laurenz I'm not looking for the max or min. I need the one where both columns are closest to their target numbers, which are not the same number. The target number will also always be in the middle of all the numbers, which is why I set the example up that way. In my example, I'm looking for 3 in the min column and 7 in the max column. This is not the real data I'm working with, but it is a simple example that shows what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom aggregate function for that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION closer_to(integer, integer, integer) RETURNS integer
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT CASE WHEN abs($1 - $3) < abs($2 - $3) THEN $1 ELSE $2 END';

CREATE AGGREGATE closest_to(integer, integer) (
   STYPE = integer,
   SFUNC = closer_to
);
```

Then you can write your query as:

```
SELECT "Business Type", "Business City",
       closest_to("Min Rating", 3) AS "Min Rating",
       closest_to("Max Rating", 7) AS "Max Rating",
FROM mytable
GROUP BY "Business Type", "Business City";
```